# Timer for applying settings WSO2 API-manager doesn't work

Tags: caching, wso2, api-manager, responsecache

I have used the WSO2 API manager in my company. When I change the settings of the available methods (scopes) or the available authorisation methods (application level security), the application of these settings takes up to 15 minutes (I tested the work of the methods through postman). This is a lot for running tests.

I followed the recommendation to change the timeout in the deployment.toml

```
[apim.cache.resource]
enable = true
expiry_time = "900s"
```

There were no such settings in my config, but I added them and change for 60s. After the reboot, the settings were applied instantly (not even after 60 seconds). However, after a while, the settings were applied again after 15 minutes. I disabled the cache altogether, but it didn't help the as well. Settings are applied quickly only the first time after restarting WSO2. Has anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

In WSO2 APIM if you update an API, the resource cache gets invalidated and the changes are reflected within a few minutes. If you want to apply the changes quickly you can restart the server and check the flow.

The default cache size of any type of cache in a WSO2 product is 10,000 elements/records. Cache eviction occurs from the 10001st element. All caches in WSO2 products can be configured using the **<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml** file. In case you have not defined a value for default cache timeout under server configurations, the defaultCacheTimeout of 15 minutes will be applied which comes by default.

```
[server]
default_cache_timeout = 15
```

Please refer https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/administer/product-configurations/configuring-caching/ for further details on caching.